# Can I package and include in the ppa the required libraries?

Tags: application-development

If some needed modules are not in the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories, can I package and include them in the submission ppa for the App Showdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the libraries are in the standard Ubuntu libraries then you don't need to include them in your package, they just need to be in the "Depends" field in your debian/control file.

If the libraries are not in the standard libraries, you can include them in a couple of ways:

1. Include them in the binary package of your application, so that they will install to the same place as your application code.
2. Include them in the source package of your application, but have them build into a separate binary package.  The separate binary package will need to follow the same rules about installing to /opt/ though, so your application will need to know to look for it there.

Comment: Dear Michael, your answer contradicts the rules of the showdown: "Novelty: [...]The application must contain exclusively original code and the Participant must be the original author of the content." This is from the rules at  http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/. You have to either redefine the rules or your answer here!

Comment: xubuntix is right, this point is not clear!

Comment: All of the apps will depend on some kind of library.  As long as you have a significant amount of original and novel code (i.e. not just wrapping a CLI program in a terminal widget), then it's acceptable.  Your submission will be judged solely on the part that is original code, the code in the libraries you use will not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries you need are available in the next release ("quantal"), you could request a backport to precise, I suppose, but I'm not sure how fast that would happen...